# i want to add data from input field to a new object that a created from a constructor and output it into the browser?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, input

First, I want to appologise for my question, but I'm learning still about JS. I created a input field of a name. Now for every input i want to be able to create a new Object from that field separately from a construcor. Then i want to be able to store each Object in a single variable as an array. And after that from that  i want to be also able to display every object that is inside that array in to the browser.I created the function that I want to run and also inside a constructur function, i created also a empty array inside, and used the push () method to add the object inside the array. I can't be able to access this inside the array later and be able to display in the browser.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function run() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

  function person(name) {
    this.name = name;
  };

  var somePerson = new person(name);
  var objArr = [];
  var all = objArr.push(somePerson);
};
```

Now i dont know if thats the way it should be, but if someone could be kind to help me out and explain a bit the error that i make in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem you're going to run into is that your arrays `objArr`, `all` are not global objects. They only exist inside the button's `onclick` function. Also, you don't need 2 of them.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var all = []; // global object

btn.onclick = function run() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

  function person(name) {
    this.name = name;
  };

  var somePerson = new person(name);

  // referencing the global object
  all.push(somePerson);
};
```

Otherwise, you've got a good solution.

Comment: It actually worked James T, if it is possible just on the question, now since I have stored Objects inside the car all= [], how would it be possible to display them in the browser for example with a paragraph, since we know that inside the array we have Objects, not primitive values. I tried the for loop with the length  property, but it won't work. So how you would go around this, for example to display them as a list of names?  And again, thank you so much for pointing me the right way with this, I think Objects are the most hardest part in JS.

Comment: If you had a paragraph like this in your markup `<p id="people"></p>` you could do something like this: 

`var p = document.getElementById('people'); p.innerText = all.map(function (person) { return person.name; }).join(', ');`

Comment: Thank you so much JamesT for your help, so so much :)